# scikit-learn optionparser error

Tags: python

From the [classification example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-text-document-classification-20newsgroups-py) on the website of scikit-learn, I'm getting the following error after executing the part with optionparser:

```
Usage: __main__.py [options]
__main__.py: error: no such option: -f
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2
To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
```

a `%tb` command gives the following output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadOptionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/kevinoost/anaconda/lib/python3.5/optparse.py in parse_args(self, args, values)
   1385         try:
-> 1386             stop = self._process_args(largs, rargs, values)
   1387         except (BadOptionError, OptionValueError) as err:

/Users/kevinoost/anaconda/lib/python3.5/optparse.py in _process_args(self, largs, rargs, values)
   1429                 # value(s) for the last one only)
-> 1430                 self._process_short_opts(rargs, values)
   1431             elif self.allow_interspersed_args:

/Users/kevinoost/anaconda/lib/python3.5/optparse.py in _process_short_opts(self, rargs, values)
   1511             if not option:
-> 1512                 raise BadOptionError(opt)
   1513             if option.takes_value():

BadOptionError: no such option: -f

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-960f3b27132a> in <module>()
     66                    "headers, signatures, and quoting.")
     67 
---> 68 (opts, args) = op.parse_args()
     69 if len(args) > 0:
     70     op.error("this script takes no arguments.")

/Users/kevinoost/anaconda/lib/python3.5/optparse.py in parse_args(self, args, values)
   1386             stop = self._process_args(largs, rargs, values)
   1387         except (BadOptionError, OptionValueError) as err:
-> 1388             self.error(str(err))
   1389 
   1390         args = largs + rargs

/Users/kevinoost/anaconda/lib/python3.5/optparse.py in error(self, msg)
   1566         """
   1567         self.print_usage(sys.stderr)
-> 1568         self.exit(2, "%s: error: %s\n" % (self.get_prog_name(), msg))
   1569 
   1570     def get_usage(self):

/Users/kevinoost/anaconda/lib/python3.5/optparse.py in exit(self, status, msg)
   1556         if msg:
   1557             sys.stderr.write(msg)
-> 1558         sys.exit(status)
   1559 
   1560     def error(self, msg):

SystemExit: 2
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html), optparse was deprecated in version 2.7 of Python; and I am using Python 3.
What do I do to fix this?

Thank you,

Regards, Kevin